# how to validate a textbox programmatically, that is at run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, runtime

i am creating textboxes when a button is clicked and again and again and so on

while accepting input i need to check if the boxes are all full,

i know how to do this using design view but how to do this using coding

that is add and validation control to the textbox when it created before initializing/adding it to the page.?

validation should be not null..

Comment: Is this a WinForms desktop application, or an ASP.Net WebForms or MVC application?

Comment: Based on his 3rd last sentence I'd say webforms.

Comment: its a web application c# asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as for validating the user input I would stay away from the ASP.Net Control Validators as hardly anyone in industry uses them.  I would use the jQuery validator plugin which is included in a new Visual Studio project by default.  You will still want Server side checking but it is much easier to call String.isNullOrEmpty(txtBox.Text) rather than using the Control Validators.